# Building up linq querys as functions

Tags: c#, linq

```
var query = (from material in dataContext.Materials
             join materialCategories in dataContext.MaterialCategories on material.Id equals
             materialCategories.Material.Id
             select new
                    {
                        material.Id,
                        material.Name,
                        material.Taken,
                        materialCategories.CategoryName
                    });
//Filter by date
query = query.Where(x => x.Taken >= minDate && x.Taken <= maxDate);
```

I want to extract the "query.Where(x => x.Taken >= minDate && x.Taken <= maxDate);" to a function that returns a query but the problem is that the function does not understand what x.Taken is.

How do i achieve this?

Comment: do some research on your own first? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx Lambdas are functions, which means what you have there is almost extracted already. The final steps are very easy, so clearly you haven't tried & didn't write the code you're showing as an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a named type instead of an unnamed one. 
Make a new class:

```
public class Category
{
    int Id;
    string Name;
    DateTime Taken;
    string CategoryName;
}
```

You can make fields as properties if you want.

Then instead of:

```
select new {...}
```

use your class:

```
select new Category {...}
```

And after that you can have this:

```
private IQueryable<Category> FilterFunction(IQueryable<Category> query)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.Taken >= minDate && x.Taken <= maxDate);
    return query;
}
```

Or use IEnumerable<> depending on what you are doing here exactly.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to promote your object to become a real type, rather than anopnymous type and then you can do:

```
 private static Func<YourObject, bool> Predicate(DateTime minDate, DateTime maxDate)
        {
            return x => x.Taken >= minDate && x.Taken <= maxDate;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass anonymous object to a method. You'd have to create a type and return new instance of that type from your first query.

Answer (score 0):

Generics will do all of this for you.

```
public IQueryable<T> betweenDates<T>(IQueryable<T> query, DateTime maxdate, DateTime mindate) where T : YourClass
{
  return query.Where(x => x.Taken >= minDate && x.Taken <= maxDate);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, would need to combine it with the answer provided by others to make a non-anonymous class, or you could provide a function that extracted a DateTime from T, but at that point the function wouldn't be much easier to call than the method its designed to replace.

Answer (score 0):

You cant do this with anonymous objects w/o some hackery with reflection. I would make a class that has these properties and return IENumerable from the function.

Answer (score -1):

You really don't want to do this.  Leaving queries in LINQ syntax lets the framework optimize the data queries.  If you pull this out into a function, all the data would have to be returned from the database and then filtered client-side.  Yuck!  For more, see "Why Convert a LINQ to SQL Query Expression into an Expression Tree?" in  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2008/01/31/expression-tree-basics.aspx

Comment: There is no DB query done until results are enumerated. You can apply any filtering to a LINQ query before it becomes an SQL query.

Comment: @Maciej - not if that filter is a function call - the framework can only work magic on expression trees.  try it!  (and then change your vote :)

Comment: Robert, sorry to say but you are wrong. I have checked. Run this with SQL Server stopped:
ProjectEntities db = new ProjectEntities();
IQueryable<User> query = from usr in db.Users select usr;
query = query.Where(u => u.UserName == "Smith");
if (query.Count() > 0) return;

It will fail no sooner than on Count.